# sql query is too complex

Tags: sql, ms-access

Please help me to simplify this complex query statement because when I run the code it will always end up with "Query is too complex" error

```
SELECT tblTimeReport.DBIDTimeReport, tblTimeReport.DBIDHumanResource
     , tblHumanResource.FullName, tblHumanResource.Title, tblTimeReport.DBIDProject
     , tblProject.ProjectID, tblProject.ProjectName, tblTimeReport.DBIDActivity
     , tblActivity.ActivityID, tblActivity.ActivityName, tblTimeReport.DateTR AS TRDate
     , tblTimeReport.StartTime, tblTimeReport.Duration, tblTimeReport.HourlyRate
     , Sum([Duration]*[HourlyRate]) AS Cost, tblTimeReport.Comments, tblTimeReport.Deleted
     , tblTimeReport.InputBy, tblHumanResourceInput.[FullName] AS InputByFullName
     , tblTimeReport.InputDate
FROM (((tblTimeReport 
LEFT JOIN tblHumanResource 
    ON tblTimeReport.DBIDHumanResource = tblHumanResource.DBIDHumanResource) 
LEFT JOIN tblHumanResource AS tblHumanResourceInput 
    ON tblTimeReport.InputBy = tblHumanResourceInput.DBIDHumanResource) 
LEFT JOIN tblProject 
    ON tblTimeReport.DBIDProject = tblProject.DBIDProject) 
LEFT JOIN tblActivity ON tblTimeReport.DBIDActivity = tblActivity.DBIDActivity
%WhereCondition%
GROUP BY tblTimeReport.DBIDTimeReport, tblTimeReport.DBIDHumanResource
       , tblHumanResource.FullName, tblHumanResource.Title, tblTimeReport.DBIDProject
       , tblProject.ProjectID, tblProject.ProjectName, tblTimeReport.DBIDActivity
       , tblActivity.ActivityID, tblActivity.ActivityName, tblTimeReport.DateTR
       , tblTimeReport.StartTime, tblTimeReport.Duration, tblTimeReport.HourlyRate
       , tblTimeReport.Comments, tblTimeReport.Deleted, tblTimeReport.InputBy
       , tblHumanResourceInput.FullName, tblTimeReport.InputDate
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: What is the `%WhereCondition%`?

Comment: Is this an Access database?

Comment: Do you need all the outer joins, or could some of them be replaced with inner joins?

Comment: @AaronLS looks like it with all the ((((()))))!

Comment: never heard about this error, anyway the compositions of the query are simple (just select from left join group by), but I guess there may be some limit in the number of group-by columns (also I've never experienced such many group-by columns - 19 columns?)

Comment: remove all the parentheses

Comment: @JNK I don't know the %WhereCondition% as it's alaways been there and running.

Comment: @AaronLS Yes it is Access database using Microsoft.Jet 4.0

Comment: @radarbob you need them for joins in access unfortunately

Comment: OMG, Access. Uh, oh. PTSD flashbacks ... I feel like The Hulk!!  ... My Marvel super hero green coder (a little nod to TDD, there) asks are the opening parents correct? Should they be enclosing the (FROM) table name?  **An alternative** is to use the GUI query builder with, say a couple field names, generate it, test it, then manually add all the others a few at a time.

Answer (score 0):

If this is for a report, as the names of your columns imply, you my be experiencing this:

> Reports create temporary queries for each section of the report,
>   including the report header, page header, group header, detail
>   section, group footer, page footer, and report footer. All of the
>   temporary queries for each report are combined into a segmented
>   virtual table (SVT). The final output must be compiled within the 64K
>   segment limit.

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/103429

So even if your query is compiled within the limits, its size is multiplied by number of sections.  The article implies newer versions of Access have increased dynamic limit, which might help.

You could try creating a view for the group by aggregation, and leave out all of the name columns, and only include the critical IDs.  Then use a join against the view to pull in names.  I'm not sure though if this would help because I don't know if the contents of the view get pulled in whenever Access compiles the query.

Comment: I saw that article but doesn't help me as I don't know how to do it :) I imported access database to sql server 2008, but for the life of me I can't get the connection string right. The connection string to the access database is just "Etitle = Config File for VS Plugin
DBPath = D:\TS_DB\accessdatabase.mdb
CredentialErrorText = Invalid Credentials
EndOfFile= True"
Any can help me to get ASP to connect to the new imported database on sql server?

Comment: See https://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server-2008/ 
**and** http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/2102.how-to-troubleshoot-connecting-to-the-sql-server-database-engine.aspx